# How to add an increment to a repeated strings

Tags: r

This is my data 
 dput(METADATA)

```
structure(list(Run = c("SRR2920466", "SRR2920477", "SRR2920478", 
"SRR2920506", "SRR2920507", "SRR2920532", "SRR2920531", "SRR2920469", 
"SRR2920470", "SRR2920481", "SRR2920482", "SRR2920500", "SRR2920501", 
"SRR2920536", "SRR2920537", "SRR2920471", "SRR2920472", "SRR2920483", 
"SRR2920484", "SRR2920505", "SRR2920538", "SRR2920539", "SRR2920475", 
"SRR2920476", "SRR2920487", "SRR2920488", "SRR2920542", "SRR2920543", 
"SRR2920555", "SRR2920559", "SRR2920570", "SRR2920573", "SRR2920578", 
"SRR2920583", "SRR2920586", "SRR2920594", "SRR2920546", "SRR2920547", 
"SRR2920548", "SRR2920549", "SRR2920550", "SRR2920551", "SRR2920553", 
"SRR2920558", "SRR2920563", "SRR2920565", "SRR2920567", "SRR2920569", 
"SRR2920572", "SRR2920575", "SRR2920577", "SRR2920580", "SRR2920582", 
"SRR2920585", "SRR2920589", "SRR2920590", "SRR2920591", "SRR2920593", 
"SRR2920554", "SRR2920552", "SRR2920556", "SRR2920557", "SRR2920560", 
"SRR2920561", "SRR2920562", "SRR2920564", "SRR2920566", "SRR2920568", 
"SRR2920571", "SRR2920574", "SRR2920576", "SRR2920581", "SRR2920584", 
"SRR2920587", "SRR2920588", "SRR2920592", "SRR2920595", "SRR2920579"
), source_name = c("HSC", "HSC", "HSC", "HSC", "HSC", "HSC", 
"HSC", "CMP", "CMP", "CMP", "CMP", "CMP", "CMP", "CMP", "CMP", 
"GMP", "GMP", "GMP", "GMP", "GMP", "GMP", "GMP", "Mono", "Mono", 
"Mono", "Mono", "Mono", "Mono", "LSC", "LSC", "LSC", "LSC", "LSC", 
"LSC", "LSC", "LSC", "Blast", "Blast", "Blast", "Blast", "Blast", 
"Blast", "Blast", "Blast", "Blast", "Blast", "Blast", "Blast", 
"Blast", "Blast", "Blast", "Blast", "Blast", "Blast", "Blast", 
"Blast", "Blast", "Blast", "Blast", "pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC", 
"pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC", 
"pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC", "pHSC")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -78L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Run = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Assay Type` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), AvgSpotLen = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), BioProject = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), BioSample = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Cell_type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Center Name` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Consent = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `DATASTORE filetype` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `DATASTORE provider` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `DATASTORE region` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), donorid = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Experiment = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), GEO_Accession = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Instrument = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), LibraryLayout = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), LibrarySelection = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), LibrarySource = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), MBases = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), MBytes = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Organism = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Platform = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ReleaseDate = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime", 
    "collector")), sample_acc = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Sample Name` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), sample_type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), source_name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `SRA Study` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

I want to have the below output to be in my final dataframe which i want to use for renaming the original file.

```
 Run        source_name
   <chr>      <chr>      
 1 SRR2920466 HSC1        
 2 SRR2920477 HSC2       
 3 SRR2920478 HSC3        
 4 SRR2920506 HSC4        
 5 SRR2920507 HSC5        
 6 SRR2920532 HSC6        
 7 SRR2920531 HSC7        
 8 SRR2920469 CMP1        
 9 SRR2920470 CMP2        
10 SRR2920481 CMP3
```

Found a solution but I have to apply it to each string in the last column

```
i1 <- !sapply(df1, is.numeric)
df1[i1] <- lapply(df1[i1], function(x) factor(replace(as.character(x),
                                                      x == "HSC", paste0(x[x=="HSC"], seq_len(sum(x == "HSC"))))))
```

Right now I am able to match repeated string in the column and add increment.How to apply it for all the other string .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to group by *source_name* and add row id, here is using *data.table* package:

```
library(data.table)

# convert to data.table
setDT(df1)

# group by source_name, and add rowid
df1[, myNewColumn := paste0(source_name, rowid(source_name))]

df1
#            Run source_name myNewColumn
#  1: SRR2920466         HSC        HSC1
#  2: SRR2920477         HSC        HSC2
#  3: SRR2920478         HSC        HSC3
#  4: SRR2920506         HSC        HSC4
#  5: SRR2920507         HSC        HSC5
#  6: SRR2920532         HSC        HSC6
#  7: SRR2920531         HSC        HSC7
#  8: SRR2920469         CMP        CMP1
#  9: SRR2920470         CMP        CMP2
# 10: SRR2920481         CMP        CMP3
# ...
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12925063/680068) for more solutions.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Wheres the OP accepted this answer, @zx8754's answer below, as well as the ones in the link they gave, are much more elegant and straightforward.

---

Here is a work-around with `table()`, `lapply()` and `seq_len()` (I have basically used your `lapply()` call on the output of a `table()` call):

```
my_counts <- table(df1$source_name)

> my_counts

Blast   CMP   GMP   HSC   LSC  Mono  pHSC 
   23     8     7     7     8     6    19 

df1 <- df1[order(df1$source_name),]

> head(df1)
          Run source_name
37 SRR2920546       Blast
38 SRR2920547       Blast
39 SRR2920548       Blast
40 SRR2920549       Blast
41 SRR2920550       Blast
42 SRR2920551       Blast

> names(unlist(lapply(my_counts, seq_len)))
 [1] "Blast1"  "Blast2"  "Blast3"  "Blast4"  "Blast5"  "Blast6"  "Blast7"  "Blast8"  "Blast9"  "Blast10" "Blast11" "Blast12" "Blast13"
[14] "Blast14" "Blast15" "Blast16" "Blast17" "Blast18" "Blast19" "Blast20" "Blast21" "Blast22" "Blast23" "CMP1"    "CMP2"    "CMP3"   
[27] "CMP4"    "CMP5"    "CMP6"    "CMP7"    "CMP8"    "GMP1"    "GMP2"    "GMP3"    "GMP4"    "GMP5"    "GMP6"    "GMP7"    "HSC1"   
[40] "HSC2"    "HSC3"    "HSC4"    "HSC5"    "HSC6"    "HSC7"    "LSC1"    "LSC2"    "LSC3"    "LSC4"    "LSC5"    "LSC6"    "LSC7"   
[53] "LSC8"    "Mono1"   "Mono2"   "Mono3"   "Mono4"   "Mono5"   "Mono6"   "pHSC1"   "pHSC2"   "pHSC3"   "pHSC4"   "pHSC5"   "pHSC6"  
[66] "pHSC7"   "pHSC8"   "pHSC9"   "pHSC10"  "pHSC11"  "pHSC12"  "pHSC13"  "pHSC14"  "pHSC15"  "pHSC16"  "pHSC17"  "pHSC18"  "pHSC19"

df1$new_col <- names(unlist(lapply(my_counts, seq_len)))

> head(df1)
          Run source_name new_col
37 SRR2920546       Blast  Blast1
38 SRR2920547       Blast  Blast2
39 SRR2920548       Blast  Blast3
40 SRR2920549       Blast  Blast4
41 SRR2920550       Blast  Blast5
42 SRR2920551       Blast  Blast6
```

You can store the initial row order somewhere to have resulting data frame in the same order the initial one.

Comment: While my answer solves your problem, the `data.table` solution suggested by @zx8754 is much more elegant and should be the accepted answer in my opinion. I have up-voted that one anyway.